# Sencha Touch, StoreManager is undefined

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I just stated a new project in Sencha Touch 2.2.1 from the SenchaCmd. Since this is my first Sencha project I am having problems with some pretty basic stuff. I'm trying to access `Ext.data.StoreManager` to load a predefined store but `Ext.data.StoreManager` is undefined, as in it seams like the loader have not loaded this file. I have tried to fix it by adding `Ext.require('Ext.data.StoreManager');` but no luck.

The project is mostly what SenchaCmd initialized with the addition of a model, a store and some changes to `app/views/Main.js`.

Any ideas?

Below is my Main.js:

```
Ext.define('DRL.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store'
    ],
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{teamName}',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('teams')
        }],
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function(self, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.require` loads files asynchronously, as well as the `requires` block. If you want StoreManager to be loaded before Ext.define, you should use `Ext.syncRequire` before the class definition.

However, there is are better and cleaner ways to achieve the same end result. For example:

app/store/TeamStore.js:

```
Ext.define('DRL.store.TeamStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'DRL.model.Team' // change your model
    ...
});
```

app/store/Main.js

```
Ext.define('DRL.view.Main', {
    ...
    store: 'DRL.store.TeamStore'
    ...
});
```

Then, **add** the `DRL.store.TeamStore` and `DRL.view.Main` to your `Ext.application` which should be in app.js.